# Choice between invoice or casual receipt during placing an order

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I want to give clients possibility to choose between invoice or casual receipt during placing an order. I use magento 1.9.2.2. I was looking for options to do that but it seems that it doesn't exist.
I feel in my bones that there is easy solution for that.
Thanks for helps!

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion read and learn this [magento extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ready-receipts.html) and re-develop for adapting to your version

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but it is not compatible with my version, beside I afraid of low pupularity of that extensions. Do you use it?

Comment: nope, so that why i put my word re-develop with that reference

Comment: I am looking for a simple resolution without many hours of coding.